# How do I make a bootable flash drive with Windows 7 on Mac (OS X) to boot into PC

Tags: windows, macos, bootloader

Basically, I am on Mac (OS X Yosemite). I need to make a bootable flash drive w/ Windows 7 to boot on to my PC. I tried using Bootcamp, but it doesn't support a 32bit operating system. I only have a Mac so I can't download Windows software

**IM TRYING TO BOOT THE USB DRIVE ON A WINDOWS PC *NOT* ON MY MAC**

Comment: What is the requirement? Maybe use Virtuals? Please try over at http://superuser.com/

Comment: No. I'm trying to install this on a Windows PC. Not on my OS X itself.

Comment: Then: http://superuser.com/questions/421402/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-windows-os-using-mac-os-x or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/how-to-create-a-windows-7-installation-usb-from-os-x

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use Windows software on MacOSX you can try [WineHQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX).
Also you can use [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) (through WineHQ for MacOSX) to burn Windows 7 on your usb!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dd in a terminal, but be sure to turn the downloaded .iso file to an img.dmg file first as per these directions:

https://www.lewan.com/blog/2012/02/10/making-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-an-apple-mac-os-x-from-an-iso

Then use F12 to choose the USB as your boot source when you stick it in your PC.

I have used this successfully when unable to use unetbootin on a linux system.  Unetbootin is not a good choice on a mac because it has bugs and does not currently work on OSX correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use a Virtual machine on your mac, download the windows os installer in the vm and transfer to your flash drive.

Long answer: My approach was to download a virtual machine using virtualbox onto my Macbook pro (Mac OS Ventura) (https://www.virtualbox.org/). I had a 32 GB (8+ GB is fine) USB flash drive connected (via dongle). I downloaded the windows 10 installer at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20. (You can use windows without a license key to download microsoft products).

You may run into the issue where the windows VM is unable to access your flash drive. You can 'sudo virtualbox', and then add the flashdrive in the vm port settings.